# Babel - Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/typeof'

Tags: transform, babeljs, typeof

Transpiling via `gulp-babel` for the server and `browserify` with `babelify` for the client - using async and await in my code. These features seem to transform just fine, but...
`Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/typeof'`

Contents of `.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["react", "es2015"],
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties",
    "transform-async-to-generator",
    "transform-runtime"
  ]
}
```

Relevant contents of `package.json`

```
"babel-core": "6.3.13",
"babel-eslint": "4.1.6",
"babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "6.3.13",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "6.3.13",
"babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.3.13",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.3.13",
"babel-preset-react": "6.3.13",
"babelify": "7.2.0",
"browserify": "12.0.1",
"gulp-babel": "6.1.0",
```

I have found a few other mentions of this, many of which seem to lead here - https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/2954

But I am getting a 404 at the link above and indeed cannot see any issues related to `babel` - https://github.com/babel/babel/issues redirects to https://github.com/babel/babel/pulls

Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Turns out I needed to take the install of `babel-runtime`, which I thought had been deprecated with the release of Babel v6.

Answer (score 8):

I was facing this error and was up whole night to find a solution, in the end just deleted `node_modules` folder, did `npm install` and it worked

Comment: Amazing how many times this solves random Webpack errors. ‍♂️

Comment: I always forget to do this but it should be my first step any time I run into any problem like this. Thanks for reminding me. That solved it.

Answer (score 5):

When I faced this, it was my version of `npm`. I had new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 and had used `nodenv` to get node 4.2.3 going, but hadn't updated npm from whatever default I had. So using `npm update -g npm` changed from version 2.14.7 to 3.10.5. I deleted `node_modules` and ran `npm i` again, and I did not see the error message after that. (Note that deleting `node_modules` and running `npm i` without updating `npm` didn't work.)

Answer (score 5):

installing babel-helpers solved the problem for me.
npm install --save babel-helpers

Comment: probably better to use --save-dev

Answer (score 1):

Looks like they have migrated all issues to another system: https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T2954

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem:

```
error in cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/interop-require-default'
```

The way I dealt with it is to:

1. delete **node_modules folder**
2. re `npm install`, and it works this time

Answer (score 0):

I Had more or less similar kind of error

**"Cannot find module 'babel-generator'**. Had no clue on how to debug them.  So I finally decided to

1. **Delete the Node Modules**, Sometimes the (windows 'del node_modules' command does not delete the node_modules) in that case ,delete them manually.
2. **npm cache clean --force**
3. **npm cache clear --force**
4. **npm prune**
5. **npm install**

this approach did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to exclude node_modules in webpack:

```
  {
    test: /\.m?js$/,
    include: [/svelte/],
    use: [babelLoader],
    exclude: /node_modules/
  },
```

For some reason, without it, it was working for another project, but not for a new one.

PS: I tried all the solutions above first with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Encountered a similar problem while running my react using CRA.

Here are the steps that did the charm for me ;).

1 - `rm -rf node_modules`

2 -  `rm package-lock.json`

3 - `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I was trying to build my angular project. Then I ran the following commands:

1. **`rm -rf node_modules`**
2. **`rm -rf package-lock.json`**
3. **`npm cache clean --force`**
4. **`npm i`**