# Error with 'babel-runtime' while trying to serve a Meteor app

Tags: node.js, meteor, babeljs

I have recently been getting off the ground with Meteor and React. I followed the [tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/react/creating-an-app) on the Meteor website with no problem.

Then I tried creating another project, trying to follow another [tutorial](https://www.codementor.io/meteor/tutorial/meteor-13-with-reactjs) (for an older version of Meteor). Somewhere along the line, Meteor started throwing up obscure errors. After trying to start fresh again, I ended up reinstalling Meteor and it stopped complaining.

However, I'm getting the same problems, again. Specifically, after creating a brand new project:

```
meteor create myproject
cd myproject
meteor
```

The server throws up the following error:

```
[...]
W20161109-03:53:42.862(1)? (STDERR) Error: The babel-runtime npm package could not be found in your node_modules
W20161109-03:53:42.862(1)? (STDERR) directory. Please run the following command to install it:
W20161109-03:53:42.863(1)? (STDERR)
W20161109-03:53:42.863(1)? (STDERR)   meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
[...]
```

I do what I'm told and attempt to install `babel-runtime` package. The server manages to successfully get off the ground, but it then throws up the following error at run-time:

```
Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/slicedToArray'
at Function.require.resolve
```

This is all still working off a freshly created project, with no extra packages installed or code changed. I have tried looking online for solutions but, while there are lots of references to bugs that have been fixed, I haven't found anything. A couple of (questions)[[Babel - Error: Cannot find module 'babel-runtime/helpers/typeof'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34321587/babel-error-cannot-find-module-babel-runtime-helpers-typeof]) on StackOverflow have suggested the following:

1. Reinstalling the NPM modules
   rm -rf node_modules
   meteor npm install
2. Updating NPM
   meteor npm update -g npm

I am using Meteor 1.4.2, NPM 3.10.9, Ubuntu 16.04.1.

Comment: Same here :/ Last update of meteor updated babel-runtime@0.1.12 => babel-runtime@1.0.0 and it doesn't work at all :(

Comment: => https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8032

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was having the same issue. After a little digging, found this: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/8019

```
* Installing the `babel-runtime` npm package in your application
  `node_modules` directory is now required for most Babel-transformed code
  to work, as the Meteor `babel-runtime` package no longer attempts to
  provide custom implementations of Babel helper functions.
Consider trying it out by using the latest release candidate (not officially released yet):

meteor update --release 1.4.2.1-rc.1
And then:

meteor npm install --save babel-runtime
```

After upgrading to 1.4.2.1-rc.1 (and then subsequently upgrading to 1.4.2.1 this morning 11/9), the error was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding package.json file inside your project directory and then run 
meteor

> npm install --save babel-runtime

in the command line.

Answer (score 0):

You may have **whitespace** in your project name. All that you have to do is create another project without whitespace in the name. I know that it's quite difficult to detect the cause from the error message, but it is what it is.

I recently faced this issue with meteor 1.11.1 and the solutions here did not work. Turns out I had whitespaces in my project name (`Ghughu Server V2`) and all I had to do is create another one without the spaces (`GhughuServerV2`).

**P.S.** It works fine even if you have whitespace in the path to your project, you just can't have whitespace in the project name. Also, just renaming the directory doesn't work. Either you have to create a brand new project or change some configuration inside (which seems impractical if you're working in a newly created project).